# How to hide particular li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ul li structure like this

```
<ul class="uniform">
    <li class="first-child odd"></li>
    <li class="even"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="even"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="even"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="simple-text odd></li>
    <li class="simple-text even"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="simple-text even"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="simple-text even"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
</ul>
```

I need to hide all the li below the "simple-text odd" li.How can we do this

I tried

```
<script>
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('li').siblings('.simple-text.odd').hide();
        }); 
</script>
```

can any one help?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`.nextAll(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) in this context,

```
$('li.simple-text.odd').nextAll('li').hide();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h9ftL/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.nextAll()` along with `.hide()`:

```
$('.simple-text.odd').nextAll().hide();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h9ftL/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('li.simple-text.odd').nextAll().hide();
```